# VBScript WSHell.Run Multiple Processes

Tags: vbscript, wsh

Does anyone know how I can accomplish the following:
I have a script that will run and get all users from AD with a homedir assigned and reset the permissions on this folder and everything under it. The problem is, it takes a very long time to complete and if I don't set the .run variable for Wait on return to true, I end up with thousands of cacls processes running. I want to limit the number of processes to say 50, and once one process finishes, move on to the next user. The script is really simple:

```
' Get Users Home Directories from AD
' Then grant Administrators FULL CONTROL and the USER MODIFY ONLY
'
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
'
' Get users with home directories
WScript.Echo "Retrieving user account names and home directories from active directory. . ."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:root\directory\ldap")
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select ds_sAMAccountName, ds_homeDirectory From ds_user WHERE ds_homeDirectory IS NOT NULL")

WScript.Echo ""

' Loop through users setting permissions
For Each oUser in colItems
    WScript.Echo "Setting permissions for " & oUser.ds_sAMAccountName & " Directory " & oUser.ds_homeDirectory
    WshShell.Run "xcacls " & oUser.ds_homeDirectory & " /y /t /g Administrators:F", 0, True
    WshShell.Run "xcacls " & oUser.ds_homeDirectory & " /e /t /g " & oUser.ds_sAMAccountName & ":C", 0, True
Next
```

Does anyone have any idea how I can do this?

Thanks

Edit::::
I think i got it figured out...

```
For Each oUser in colItems
    numrunning = HowMany
    while numrunning > 25
        WScript.Echo "Waiting for other processes to finish"
        WScript.Sleep 10000
        numrunning = HowManyRunning
    wend
    WScript.Echo "Setting permissions for " & oUser.ds_sAMAccountName & " Directory " & oUser.ds_homeDirectory
    WshShell.Run "xcacls " & oUser.ds_homeDirectory & " /y /t /g Administrators:F", 0, False
    WshShell.Run "xcacls " & oUser.ds_homeDirectory & " /e /t /g " & oUser.ds_sAMAccountName & ":C", 0, False
Next

Function HowManyRunning()
  Dim Proc1,Proc2,Proc3
  Set Proc1 = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")
  Set Proc2 = Proc1.ExecQuery("select * from win32_process" )
  HowMany=0
  For Each Proc3 in Proc2
    If LCase(Proc3.Caption) = "xcacls.exe" Then
      HowMany=HowMany + 1
    End If
  Next
End Function
```

Comment: You can answer your own question you know!

Comment: I would suggest making it a login script, but I guess you have a reason why not to do that.